# how to display new line input text in new line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I want to display new-line text input taken in textfield in new-line that is as below

```
Hello,                            \\1st line
This is how i want to display,     \\2nd line
such input is given to textfield.  \\3rd line
```

I am using following code by using this code, what text i am entering in new line it not displaying at all.(not also 1st line text) This code only displaying single line text

```
{% for obj in post %}
<script>
var str= '{{ obj.content }}';
$(".statbox").prepend("<div class='box2'>" + str + "</div>");
</script>
{% endfor%}
```

if i am using following code then it displaying all new line entering text but in only single line as below

```
{% for obj in post %}
    <div class='box2'> {{ obj.content }} </div>
{% endfor%}
```

and its output

```
Hello,\\1st line\\ This is how i not want to display, \\2nd line\\ such input is given to textfield.  \\3rd line
```

so how can i display all new-line enterd input in new line using js code becoz i want to disply those text in `prepend` manner

Thnaks in adv...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because HTML doesn't respect whitespace, unless within certain elements.

To achieve what you require you can replace the line breaks in the string with `<br />` tags, like this:

```js
var str = `Hello,
  This is how i want to display,
  such input is given to textfield.`;
$(".statbox").prepend('<div class="box2">' + str.replace(/\n/g, '<br />') + '</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="statbox"></div>
```

Comment: Its working for manually given string, but not for me... In my case that string is in django object i.e. in `{{ obj.content }}`  i taken that content in str but its not working... @Rory McCrossan

Comment: It's possible. Could you edit your question to include the actual JS code that's output from your Django object

Comment: Wow Done...!  I was using  '   ' instead of  `  `  so that was not upto the mark. Thanks a lot.... @Rory McCrossan